# Change base location of HorizontalAlignment property in case of using Centered value

Tags: wpf

I want to create a centered text according to the available area without overlapping any other items in a row.

What I have is a `Grid` with 2 columns. Column_0 holds an icon, and Column_1 holds the title. Something like this:

```
|icon|    this is a centered text     |
```

Icon column has a predefined width, let it be e.g. 30 px. The remaining area is free for the title. In Xaml:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

I would like to place the title with the following criteria:

- Place the title centered taking the whole area into account.
- Title should not overlay the icon in any circumstances

Instead of the first result I would like to achieve something like this:

```
This is the center of the whole grid
And the text is aligned to this point.
                  |
                  V
__________________|_________________
|icon| this is a centered text     |
```

- `ColumnSpan` does not work; if the text is longer than the available area it will overlay the icon.

If I could make something like this that would be great:

```
HorizontalAlignmentCenterPositionOffset = -30
```

Comment: What should happen when the text is about to overlap the icon? The text should be move to right direction?

Comment: @BeholdTheLight: Can't you use the `Margin` property to define the offset?

Comment: @emoacht Yes, I want the text to equally spread equivalently both of the directions then if it hits the icon's space then start spreading to the right.

Comment: @mm8 By setting the margin to e.g. -30 text starts to overlay the icon.

Comment: Then you have obviously set it to the wrong value. You need to take the width of the icon into account when you calculate the margin.

Comment: By setting the margin to a negative value the element having that very margin will overlap whether I have calculated Margin or any e.g. -20, -50, -100.

Answer (score 0):

`HorizontalAlignment` is not the only way to place an element at the center. You can do the same without it.

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="cernted text"/>
</Grid>
```

Then, you can set `MinWidth` of left column so that the centered element would not go left beyond the minimum width.

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="30"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="cernted text"/>
</Grid>
```

**Edit**

You sample code should be modified as follows:

```xml
<Grid Margin="50" Height="30" MaxWidth="300">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="30"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <!-- This element represents the icon -->
    <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Fill="Blue" Opacity="0.5" Width="30" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>

    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Centered text" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

    <!-- Additional elements show correct place -->
    <TextBlock Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="0,-40,0,0" Text="This point shall be the center point of the text below" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="0,-20,0,0" Text="|" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    <Rectangle Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Fill="Red" Opacity="0.5" />
</Grid>
```

To enable to scroll vertically when the text goes beyond 270, add `MaxWidth` to TextBlock.

```xml
<!-- This element represents the icon -->
<Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Fill="Blue" Opacity="0.5" Width="30" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
<ScrollViewer Grid.Column="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
              VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <!-- AS SOON AS I INTRODUCE THIS SCROLLBAR EVEN THE MARKING ELEMENTS DISAPPEAR... IDK WHY :/ -->
    <TextBlock Text="Centered text which can grow as long as it wants to until it reaches 300 px overally"               
               TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxWidth="270"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: I see the point here, you make text centered by sorrounding it with two identically wide columns. However, this approach does not work well, or to say it works exactly the same as HorizontalAlignment set to Centered.

Comment: I uploaded the code and the image.
Code: https://pastebin.com/BXYAGrry
Image: https://pasteboard.co/2Hm38mOMJnAu.png

Comment: The column you added at far left changed alginment. I added how to modify your sample code.

Comment: Thank you very much I really got what I wanted, however one thing does not work which is my Scrollbar. It worked before, now completely disappeared. I want to make the title scrollable if does not fit. Can you help me with this extra step? Beside of this your solution worked pretty well even though I have problems to understand why does it work like this :D

Comment: I created a new paste, here you can find it: https://pastebin.com/ttnUsVYj

Comment: Added. I am not sure what you mean by "THE MARKING ELEMENTS" though.

Comment: Thanks, I’ll check this next morning. Marking elements are the text saying “Here should be the center…” and the vertical line “|” which indicated the exact center of the Grid.

Comment: I'm struggling with this one for hours, I can't make it to work. 270 is arbitrary, I want it to use the AUTO functionality which suppossed to work somehow. I wrote a converter where I was possible to create infinite loop in XAML for the first time in history I guess. Yay!
This converter tried to calculate the MaxWidth for my TextBlock by subtracting it's ActualWidth from the parent's ActualWidth. Now its ActualWidth changes indefinitely...